# Ayuda para poder integrar Angular 4 con libreria externa

Tags: angular4

Buenos días, estoy creando una aplicación con Angular 4 y deseo poder integrar librerías js a la solución como son:

1- http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/

2- https://evoluxbr.github.io/verto-docs/

Sin embargo no hemos podido incorporarlas, ha pesar de poner la librería en el archivo .angular-cli.json.

¿Qué más debemos configurar para poder trabajar con estas librerías desde angular 4?

Answer (score 0):

Para el uso de librerías ***no-angular*** tienes 2 opciones para la importación y 1 para su utilización.

> Importar el script.

```
// En el index.html

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

// O bien en .angular-cli.json

{
    "scripts": [
      "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
    ]
}
```

> Utilizar en cualquier fichero TypeScript declarando la variable principal de tu librería al principio del fichero después de los imports.

```
declare var $: any; // Ejemplo para jQuery
```